# IE8 compatiblity options

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So I'm working on a site now that needs to be compatible with IE8, using HTML5 code and according to web validator the HTML and CSS3 are completely correct with no errors at all. In all the browsers I look in everything is fine (including IE 11), but in IE8 NOTHING looks like it should look. I have no background color in my content area, my pictures all all over the place, most of my font isn't showing up like it's supposed to, my site on IE8 is a mess. Is there any simple way to make my site compatible with IE8? I have been Google searching for the past two days, found a few sites that claimed they would make things better and don't and others that help just a little (like maybe my content area shows up, but not my nav menu) and I need to know how to fix my site so that it will show up correctly. If anyone out there could provide any help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad, and fails #3 of the "what kind of questions should I ask here", which requires demonstrating a minimal understanding of the problem. It is well-known that older versions of IE, IE8 included, do not support large swathes of HTML5 and CSS3. You can either use new technology or support outdated browsers, but not both.

Comment: start with Modernizr -- it helps to bridge some of the gaps. But you'll need to then start tracking down problems one by one.

Comment: Okay, but I've seen command things where it has like <!--[If ie8 (something)]--> how does that work? Can I just make a 1.0 traditional site and used that with the if command? I'll admit I'm an amateur and used to working with the newer stuff, but I can learn how to do the other stuff if I get the chance.

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx. It's ugly, but i find it easier in some cases to just use IE only code-blocks. Besides normal conditionals like the one you quoted, downlevel-revealed conditional comments are also useful. Basically, they will be run in all browsers _except_ the ones you select for.

Comment: Those are 'conditional comments'. IE (only) reads what is in the brackets, but in theory other browsers should ignore them since ultimately they are just <!-- comments -->. [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Those comments are parsed by IE and ignored by other browsers. So you can load CSS and JS conditionally to override your modern browser directives.

Comment: But follow the feature detection link in the MSDN article listed above. This is what Modernizer helps with. JQuery hides a lot of differences too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't understand many of the newer HTML5 elements. You need to include this script to ensure it will recognize and, by virtue of recognition, style those elements:

https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: I have tried this ever shape form and fashion I could think to try and nothing works.

Comment: I finally got it to work, and its so BEAUTIFUL! Thanks so much man.